# Default libraries linked in by gcc?

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos, gcc

Let's say I have a very simple C file (called foo.c):

```
int main()
{
   printf("foo");
   return 0;
}
```

Now I call gcc:

```
gcc foo.c
```

When I call gcc (with no options, as in the above example), what libraries are linked in by default and where are they located? (On Mac OS X 10.7)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `-v` option to `gcc` will cause it to dump information about the default options it will use including the library paths and default libraries and object files that will be linked in.

If you give the `-Wl,--verbose` option, gcc will pass the `--verbose` to the linker which will dump exactly where it's looking for libraries, including both failed and successful searches.

Combine both options, and you'll see exactly what libraries are linked in, and why they're being linked in.

```
gcc -v foo.c -Wl,--verbose
```

Comment: On my mac, ld says that --verbose is an unrecognized option

Comment: @user1516425: oh - when I see `gcc`, I just assume that GNU `ld` is involved.  Looking at some docs for the Xcode linker, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ld.1.html, you might want to see if the `-t` linker option will do the trick. Some other options to consider can be found under the "Options for introspecting the linker" heading on that page.

Answer (score 0):

ldd binary_name. http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=ldd&category=1&russian=2

Comment: Note he said Mac OS X 10.7, where there is no `ldd`.  The equivalent is `otool -L`.

Answer (score -2):

The standard libraries are linked by default. they are located in /usr in linux machines