# pthread library inclusion at (linking?) step

Tags: g++, pthreads

I'm trying to compile a program provided to me.  I noticed in the Makefile it runs the command

```
g++ -o test [...] -lpthread
```

I noticed the pthread library file is in /lib/libpthread.so.0 , but when I try to make the target, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem but you should use `-pthread` rather than `-lpthread`.

Comment: The `-Wl,--verbose` option will show you where GCC is looking for the library, which might help you figure out why it's not finding it.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11481258/12711 for more details.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use `-lpthread`, you need a `libpthread.a` library archive and this is for static linking. `libpthread.so.0` is a shared object which means it is used for dynamic linking. See [GCC Link Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: `-l` is used for dynamic linking also. Your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: OK. Didn't know that gcc is now smart enough to try many variants of files `liblibname.a`, `liblibname.so`, `libname.a`, ... for the linking option `-llibname`

Comment: That's been the case pretty much forever. It's nothing new.