# Is there a way to find which library file is to be used when compiling?

Tags: c++, gcc, ld

When compile with `g++ -lboost_system code.cpp -o a.out`, the linker will try to find the library file (libboost_system.so). What if there are more than one such file existing in different directory, how can I know which one is been chosen?

PS: I try to compile a project, it needs a high version of libboost than the one been installed. I compile libbost_1_55_0 and install it to `/usr/local/`, however, when I try to compile the project, it still report errors about libboost, it seems that the old version is been used rather than the new version. I want to make out which version of boost is been used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11481258/12711

Answer (score 0):

From the gcc man page:

> -Ldir
>              Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.